# How to transfer login and password across modules in Express

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

I want to every user logs to app, login to db with own login and password.
I've try something like this, creating connection pool in middleware db module:

```
    var config = {
        server: "",
        database:"",
        options: {
            "enableArithAbort": true
        },
        authentication: {
            type: "azure-active-directory-password",
            options: {
                userName: name, // email
                password: password // password
            }
        },
        pool: {
            max: 50,
            min: 0,
            idleTimeoutMillis: 1800000
        }
        module.exports = {
        getPool: function (req, res, next) {
            if (pool) return pool; // if it is already there, grab it here
            name = req.session.email
            password = req.session.password
            pool = new mssql.ConnectionPool(config);
            return pool;
        }
}
```

And in login module:

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
        req.session.email = req.body.email;
        req.session.password = req.body.password;
        pool.connect(function(err){
            if (err) {
                throw err
            } else {
                console.log("connect!")
            }
        })
    })
```

Problem is, I can't start server:

```
..middleware\db.js:35
        name = req.session.email
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of undefined
```

For now I create connection pool in every single route, and I don't need to transfer any data across modules, but I think this is bad.

Comment: Why are you storing password and email in session?

Comment: I try many things to transfer data to separate function in middleware.
Problem is I need to connect to db using azure-active-directory-password

Comment: can you explain what are trying to archieve by " to transfer data to separate function in middleware". Maybe I could suggest best solution

Comment: I want to by logging in to app, pass login and password to middleware and create there connection pool using email and password from login form. 
I've trying do that with session or global variable. I want to do that to use the same connection pool in every route.
Simplifying signing to app is equal to signing to azure db.

Comment: now I get it. Why don;t you store these credentials in node env

Comment: Or does your app require every user to have azure account and database connect to your service? Which I believe is not what you intend

Comment: I want to every user can signin with domain password. I want to everyone connect to db with azure active directory password, then I know who and what does on tables